# Is there no longer a special spam/offensive flag limit?

Tags: discussion, flags

Are spam/offensive flags still meant to have their separate special flag limit, or have they been unified with the new flagging system? Previously, there were less spam/offensive flags allowed, but recently I attempted to flag something as spam and no special flag limit showed up upon clicking the "spam" option.

Comment: There's a flag count (e.g. the helpful flag count visible in your profile) an a flag limit which limits how many flags you can make per day. I _think_ you're talking about the latter, but to differentiate it from the profile flag count, I've edited your question to talk in terms of a limit rather than a count.